# VirtualBox: no USB 2 mode in settings

Tags: usb, virtualbox, virtual-machine

```
VirtualBox 6.1.6 r131729
Host OS: Ubuntu 18.04 64-bit
Guest OS: Windows 10 64-bit
```

Guest additions `v. 6.1.6` are installed.

I don't see USB 2 and USB 3 controller modes on USB settings page; Only `USB 1.1 (OHCI) Controller` available. Why?

[image: Available usb controller modes]